# Why can't you assert the response status in a FunctionalJavascript test?

Tags: testing

If I do this in a FunctionalJavascript test:

```
    $assert_session->statusCodeEquals(200);
```

I get:

> Behat\Mink\Exception\UnsupportedDriverActionException: Status code is not available from Drupal\FunctionalJavascriptTests\DrupalSelenium2Driver

Why though?

Answer (score 1):

This has a little history behind it.

[Mink](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/) is the library that build on top of [phpunit](https://phpunit.de/) for functional testing:

> One of the most important parts in the web is a browser. A browser is the window through which web users interact with web applications and other users. Users are always talking with web applications through browsers.
>
> So, in order to test that our web application behaves correctly, we need a way to simulate this interaction between the browser and the web application in our tests. We need Mink.

Mike supports several ways to simulate a browser, through [drivers](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/guides/drivers.html).

Normal functional tests use `BrowserTestBase`, which uses the [Goutte](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/drivers/goutte.html) driver.

Javascript tests used to use the PhantomJS driver, but that is an abandoned project now.  This has been migrated to `WebDriverTestBase`, which uses the [Selenium2](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/drivers/selenium2.html) driver.

Selenium2 essentially does a remote control of a headless browser, through the WebDriver protocol.  This allows you to run the same driver against multiple browsers (Chrome, Firefox, and I think Safari).

The problem is that Selenium2 gives you the advantage of a real browser, but has limitations.  It is slow.  The other is that there isn't full parity between the other drivers, and [getting the response code is one of these limitations](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141#issuecomment-191404986).

So, this is a Mink/Selenium2 problem and not a genral Drupal testing framework problem.

Comment: More background
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141

Comment: Ok, but why can't Selenium2 do it?

Comment: @joachim The Selenium team have decided that they do not want to implement this in WebDriver, https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141#issuecomment-191404986